# Control multiple-select box using a single select box using javascript

Tags: php, javascript

```
`<select multiple="multiple" name="state[]" id="state">
<option value="">Select a State</option>
<?php 
foreach($state_list as $key=>$value){
echo "<option value=\"$key\"";
if($html['state']==$key|| $row['state']==$key){
echo ' selected="selected"';
}
echo ">$value</option>\n";                                     
}?>
</select> </p>`


<p>Select A Country
<select name="country" id="country">
<option value="0">Select a Country</option>
<option value="USA">USA</option>                             
<option value="UK">UK</option>    
</select> </p>
```

I have two select boxes 1)state[] 2) country . What is want is that "If the selected country is not USA, disable the multi-select box which consists all the USA states". Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you have the jQuery Framework on your site or are you using plain JavaScript?

Comment: I'm using plain Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following if you have jQuery:

```
$('#country').change(function () {
    if($('#country').val() != "USA") {
        $('#state').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('#state').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Or if you are using plain JavaScript:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("country");
elem.onchange = function () {
     if(elem.options[e.selectedIndex].value != "USA") {
         document.getElementById('state').disabled = "disabled";
     }
     else {
         document.getElementById('state').removeAttribute("disabled");
     }
}
```

This will disable the state combo box when the country combo box contains a value that is not "USA". When the selected country is "USA", it will remove the disabled attribute and make it usable again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @srinivas No problem man. Glad I could assist. Good luck and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 2):

Add this Javascript to your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.onload = function() {
    var selectCountry = document.getElementById('country');
    selectCountry.onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById('state').disabled = (selectCountry.value != 'USA')? true : false;
    };
};
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: @srinivas No problem. If you are satisfied with any answer please choose to accept one of them. And good luck to you! :)